# LEFT JOIN on table returns array with one element instead of empty array, when using json_build_object

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    array_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', usn.id,
            'schemaName', usn.schema_name
        )
    ) AS schemas
FROM dev.users u
FULL OUTER JOIN dev.user_schema_names usn ON u.id = usn.user_id
WHERE u.email = $1
GROUP BY u.id
```

But for some odd reason, this returns the following:

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  schemas: [ { id: null, schemaName: null } ]
}
```

The `dev.user_schema_names` has no records in it. I am expecting `schemas` to be an empty array `[]`. If I insert records in `dev.user_schema_names`, then it works just fine, however.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using something else instead of `json_build_object`?

Comment: This is what I expected for a left join (more or less, your formatting is weird for `psql` output, so presumably you using something that does an automatic row_to_json equivalent on the output).  Your expectation is wrong, but since you didn't describe the reasoning behind the expectation, we can't say where it went awry.  You could use a CASE to detect the singular output you don't want and convert it to what you do want.

Comment: I'm using `pg` for node. Why do I need to use a case? It's an obvious expectation, that if no rows are found, then the resulting array for `rows` should be an empty array, is it not?

Comment: But rows were found, they just had NULL values for some of the columns.  Because that is what left joins do.